# Запятая на стыке союзов после точки с запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

*У предприятия может быть первоклассный финансист, качественный товар, идеально настроенная логистика; но[,] если маркетинг хромает, оно не выживет.*

В начале предложения, после точки, союз "но" считается присоединительным и запятая на стыке союзов запятая не ставится, если нет паузы. В случае, когда союз "но" стоит после запятой, запятая на стыке союзов ставится при отсутствии в главном предложении второй части двойного союза "то". Так вот, а при точке с запятой какое правило следует применять, для точки или для запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**У предприятия может быть первоклассный финансист, качественный товар, идеально настроенная логистика; но если маркЕтинг хромает, оно не выживет.**

Вероятно, формально здесь допускаются оба варианта, но именно в этом предложении лучше обойтись без лишних запятых.

Интонационно союз НО также лучше отнести к придаточной части предложения.

Comment: Раз отсутствие запятой возможно, получается, точка с запятой ближе к точке и применяется правило для запятой на стыке присоединительного и подчинительного союзов в начале предложения, правильно?

Comment: Sharon, ударение спорное. Сравните: Предприятие может существовать с плохим финансистом, некачественным товаром, при плохо настроенной логистике;  но если маркЕтинг хромает, оно не выживет.

Comment: А у автора, по-моему, ударение на *хромает*: маркетинг хромАет.

Comment: @ М_Г Мне кажется, что ударение ставится на "маркетинг", так как до этого были перечислены разные темы (финансист, товар, логистика), но в принципе ударение на "хромает" тоже возможно. Но для включения союза НО в придаточное предложения это не так важно, а важно не делать паузу после союза, важно не выделять его. Думаю, что отсутствие запятой вообще характерно для нераспространенных придаточных.

Comment: @ Василий Ефименко Да, по семантике и интонации точка с запятой ближе к точке, чем к запятой.

Answer (score 1):

**У предприятия может быть первоклассный финансист, качественный товар, идеально настроенная логистика; но если маркетинг хромает, оно не выживет.**

Я думаю, интонационно точка с запятой ближе к точке (более длительная пауза), поэтому я бы выбрал вариант по типу "*но* в начале предложения".